# How to run checkstyle on edited lines in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I'm currently working on large codebase where there are already many violated checkstyle rules. However we are now pushed towards sticking to those rules more strictly (the rules always had been in place, but weren't enforced).

So I would like to see the violations in code I edited. But I don't want to see every violation, because this is just distracting.

Is there a option, save action or a builder I can add to the project to do this?

I haven't found anything except for the run in background builder that does check all the files in the eclipse project.

I'm running eclipse mars with the eclipse checkstyle plug-in 6.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Eclipse-CS only runs Checkstyle on changed files (via the Checkstyle builder). But that is for performance reasons. You still *see* all issues flagged in the entire code base. The 'Problems' view in Eclipse can be configured to show only the warnings on the currently selected file. In my experience, these mechanisms combined are enough to efficiently navigate a code base with tens of thousands of warnings.

You will still have the drawback of the prolonged wait for the initial build, because all files are checked at least once. If that is a problem, you can configure the Checkstyle builder to not run on files that are in sync with the source repository:

[image]